# Double indexing in a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a 2D array of coordinates and apply a function to them, but I am having trouble indexing both the x and y positions properly. Here is my code:

```
for i,j in range(330):
    aperture = phot.aperture.CircularAperture((xy[i,j]),3)
    photometry = phot.aperture_photometry(xy, aperture)
```

the xy array has a size of (330,2), and I want the function to be applied to each set of coordinates, but instead I receive the error `cannot unpack non-iterable int object`. How can I solve this?

Comment: what do you spect to be your i,j index?

Comment: `for i,j in range(330)` this is incorrect. You will get only one value each time.

Comment: Are you looking to use `xy[i,1]` and `xy[i,2]` ?

Comment: can you provide the full code please?

Comment: @UlisesBussi I want the i index to refer to the x coordinate and the j index to be the y coordinate

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes, that makes sense, so then the first line is just for i in range(330)?

Comment: Is `xy` a list of lists or a numpy array? For a list of lists, it's better to iterate values directly (use `enumerate` for coordinates). For a numpy array, there are more appropriate ways (map, apply, etc).

Comment: yes but what's the variation for i and for j ? you trying i,j =(0,0) -> i,j=(1,1) ? i,j=(0,0) ->i,j=(0,1) ....

Answer (score 3):

to address each element of xy array, you need to do something like this

```
for i in range(330):
    for j in range(2):
        aperture = phot.aperture.CircularAperture((xy[i,j]),3)
        photometry = phot.aperture_photometry(xy, aperture)
```